# Inaccuracy of a RS-232 baudrate

Tags: uart, rs232

I write a simple software implementation of UART for my ATtiny. My CPU isn't fast, so I should choose low baudrate. Nevertheless I want to use as high baudrate as possible. And I can estimate the inaccuracy of a baudrate in the my implementation.

What is the maximum possible relative inaccuracy of a RS-232 baudrate for correct communication with other devices? Does the RS-232 standard define it?

Comment: rough guess - with 10 bits (start, stop, 8 data) if the timing was half a bit out by the end there would be an error, so 0.5 / 10 = 5%. P.S. if you calibrate the RC clock you can get more accurate timing. I read somewhere that out of the box it might not be quite good enough.

Comment: Contrary to what everyone seems to think the asynchronous serial data format is NOT defined in the RS-232 standard. Worse, I have never found an official definition of it anywhere.

Comment: The trick is to retrieve and synchronize to the clock by synchronizing to the slopes in the data signal. Average the timing over a few bits and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a formal definition. But consider this:

An RS232 character is about 10 symbols long (start, 8 bits, stop ).

If you start decoding halfway through a symbol, and your clock is 5% off, after 10 symbols you will have drifted off target by 50% of a symbol width; i.e. 5% is the maximum possible tolerable error. And that assumes the other end is clocked correctly; if it had an error in the other direction, you would decode it incorrectly.

So a 2.5% error in opposite directions at each end would also be on the edge of failing.

Signal integrity problems caused by cable length will only make this worse.

So practically, an error below 5% will work with a "good" clock at the other end and a very short cable; for robust communications you want a clock error below 2%, and better than that to support long cables.

Now find out what your ATTiny is capable of, at different baud rates and CPU clocks...

Comment: UART may synchronize using x 16X clock on the leading edge of the start bit and then center sample on remaining data bits. This also introduces a clock error of 1/16 of a bit max. in 10 bits or 0.67% so consider 4% max in theory and better to choose2$ in practise as Brian said.